# passing a position mutiple times into a shader in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a track in unity by using nodes, this works however to show the track i am trying to use a shader that changes the textures at the position of the node. This how ever only chnages the texture for the first node and then stops. is this a shader limitation or am i missing something?

Shader code:

```
 Properties
    {
        _NodePos("Node position", vector) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        _Dist("Distance", float) = 5.0
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _SecondayTex("Secondary texture", 2D) = "white"{}
        _NumOfPeices("Pieces",float) = 5.0
            _Color("colour", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
            _isdone("isdone",float) = 0.0
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 4.0
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPos : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                // We compute the world position to use it in the fragment function
                o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.texcoord;
                return o;
            }
            uniform float4 _Color;
            float4 _NodePos;
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _SecondayTex;
            float _Dist;
           float _NumOfPeices;
           float _isdone;
           fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
           {
               // Depending on the distance from the player, we use a different texture
             
                if (distance(_NodePos.xyz, i.worldPos.xyz) < _Dist)
                {

                return tex2D(_SecondayTex, i.uv);
                }
                 else
                     return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                   
               
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
```

Script code to give the position:

```
  public void createDirtTrack()
    {
        foreach (NodeScript n in GD.path)
        {
            if (GD.path.Contains(n))
            {


                Mat.SetVector("_NodePos", n.worldPos);
                Mat.SetFloat("_Dist", Radius);
            }
        }}
```

Final result in the unity scene:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obb0y.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might need to instance the material on the object and set the shader of that material. Something along the lines of getting the material reference and creating a new instance, then setting the material to that new instanced material. `Material Mat = new Material(GetComponent<Renderer>().material);` and then set the material `GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Mat`. After that try setting the properties. Obviously, cache the `GetComponent` but for simplicity, I used it twice in this comment.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, however i am still unsure what you mean? do you mean add this to each node or the terrain? and if so where would i call it? Thank you once again

Comment: No worries I can clarify. I believe the issue is that each `Node` you have is sharing the same material. The material is using the shader code you have provided. When setting the properties from code, it overwrites the previous instance. So every call is made to the last `Node`. One each `NodeScript` I would store a new instanced material, then in your `foreach` loop call an `Init` function to set the values of the shader on that instanced material. I can write up a more detailed answer, but I am not 100% ure if this is your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I do believe this could be the issue. It definitely makes the most sense. If you could write a more detailed answer it would be greatly appreciated. until then i will keep working on it and see what i can make work, thank you again

Comment: Looked into your issue a bit more, I am not very experienced with shaders, so try the solution I just posted. If that does not work, I can write up a different solution that should work.

Comment: Thank you, That solution did not seem to work it only changed the texture at one position still. Thank you, i also have very little experience with shaders so this is all new to me.

Comment: I updated the answer. I was not properly accessing the property block. Did a bit more reading.

Answer (score 0):

Before rewriting the structure of your code to instance materials, I would try adding [PerRendererData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialProperty.PropFlags.PerRendererData.html) above the vector and float.

```
Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData]_NodePos("Node position", vector) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        [PerRendererData]_Dist("Distance", float) = 5.0
...
```

I do not have a ton of experience writing shaders, but the docs specify that this value can only be changed by code, is read-only in the editor, and will replace the material data values with whatever values are assigned at runtime.

Edit: Further reading, to use the new values you must access the [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html). Your code would need to change a bit.

```
public void createDirtTrack()
{
    foreach (NodeScript n in GD.path)
    {
        if (GD.path.Contains(n))
        {
            // grab the renderer of the current node
            Renderer tmpRend = n.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            
            // create a new material property block
            MaterialPropertyBlock tmpBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
            
            // get our properly block of the current nodes renderer
            tmpRend.GetPropertyBlock(tmpBlock);
            
            // apply our changes
            tmpBlock.SetVector("_NodePos", n.worldPos);
            tmpBlock.SetFloat("_Dist", Radius);
            
            // now apply our changes
            tmpRend.SetPropertyBlock(tmpBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming the `NodeScript` is on each `Node`, which has the `Renderer` with the `Material` you are changing. If you are calling this code often, I would add a function to `NodeScript`, where you cache the renderer and apply the changes locally. As the method has the word `create` I assume this is called once to instantiate your track so the use of `GetComponent` in the method is not terrible. Let me know if this works for you, I have never used property blocks.

Comment: Hi thank you, I'm sorry i don't know if i explained correctly but the material that is being changed is on the terrain and terrain only, i just want it to change in the location of the nodes. sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Cooljest4123 If you are using just 1 material then your code will not work. You would need to add a new material to the ground pieces and attach the shader to the material of those objects. Then there will be a small sphere around each ground piece.

Comment: The other option is to pass in an array of positions and floats, then have it draw each object with this data. You would need to change the shader code though.